# Calculate overlay area - QGIS (Essen)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, overlay

I have create a layer that is the represents the overlay areas based on some condition. The overlay is represented in purple:

[image]

I want to know the area of the overlay - which is a separate layer that has been created using the geoprocessing tool intersect. To calculate the area of the overlay I have done the following:

select the layer overlay in the layer panel -> right click on open attribute table -> activate toggle editing mode -> open field calculator -> write query as following:

[image]

The problem is that no calculations are made. In the attribute table there is only *NULL* for every cell entry.

Am i missing something? **How can I calculate the area of overlay?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to write `$area` instead of `"field_name" = $area` under Expression's panel